# dsh/pdsh tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: ssh, tput

I am trying to make dsh/pdsh work on OpenSUSE 15.5 however I cannot overwhelm issue with tput and my env variables..

```
[~ @OpenSUSE15Lab]: user_name$ dsh -v -m remote_host "hostname --fqdn"
Setting verbose to  [1]
 Parameter remoteshell is ssh
Using ssh as the remote shell
 Parameter showmachinenames is 1
Setting pipe option to  [1]
 Parameter waitshell is 1
Setting wait-shell to  [1]
Loading config file /home/user_name/.dsh/dsh.conf
Verbose flag on
Adding machine remote_host to list
--- Executing on remote_host 
DUMPing parameters passed to llexec
[remote_host] [hostname --fqdn] 
remote_host: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
remote_host: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote_host: remote_host.fqdn
--- Terminated running
```

I have got in my .bashrc lines at the end:

```
export PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=error'

if tty -s
then
  if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
    fgRed=$(tput setaf 1)     ; fgGreen=$(tput setaf 2)  ; fgBlue=$(tput setaf 4)
    fgMagenta=$(tput setaf 5) ; fgYellow=$(tput setaf 3) ; fgCyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    fgWhite=$(tput setaf 7)   ; fgBlack=$(tput setaf 0)
    bgRed=$(tput setab 1)     ; bgGreen=$(tput setab 2)  ; bgBlue=$(tput setab 4)
    bgMagenta=$(tput setab 5) ; bgYellow=$(tput setab 3) ; bgCyan=$(tput setab 6)
    bgWhite=$(tput setab 7)   ; bgBlack=$(tput setab 0)
  fi
fi
```

Also in /etc/profile line at the front:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

On targeted system just add in the front of /etc/profile:
export TERM=xterm